# How to decorate or highlight some dates on Calendar VIew in android?

Tags: android, customization, android-calendar

In my project, I am getting a response from server.In that response there will be some dates of current month.I want to show those dates with different text color, different background color on calendar view.I waat to differentiate those dates from other dates.
I read that in default Calendar view we can't do that.
I've searched for external libraries.
I found MCalendar library.But in that library the calendar view not suits me.
Can anyone give me solution for this or direct me to perfect library I am looking for?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey after two days search I found this library.
The library name is Material Calenderview: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview.

We can add custom colors to a list dates by using adding Decorator to this calendar view. If you go there you can see the documentation for adding decorator a calendar view fir highlighting some dates.